# find in mongoDB documents with filled nested array and build new result object

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have some document with this structure - the category field can also be empty

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "category" : [
        { "target" : "element 1" },
        { "target" : "element 2" }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "category" : [
        { }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : "3",
    "category" : [
        { "target" : "element 1" },
        { "target" : "element 2" }
    ]
},
```

What I need is a result like

```
{ id: 1, element: "element 1" },
{ id: 1, element: "element 2" },
{ id: 3, element: "element 1" },
{ id: 3, element: "element 2" }
```

That means first I have to check for all documents which have target elements:

```
var result = db.collection.find({}, { 'category.target': 1})
```

1) But this doesn't work, as I still get the empty doc (2).

2) Second I need to get a new result element for each element in the target-array. I think aggregate isn't the correct way as there has to be new objects for each element. And map is only to nave the fields.

So I think I have to iterate over the results and build a new object, correct?

```
result.forEach(function($res){
    // do a new foreach for every element in target-array?
    newResult.push({ id: res._id, element: res.element });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [`aggregate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate) which, unlike `find`, allows you to reshape documents.

```javascript
db.test.aggregate([
    // Duplicate each doc, once per category element
    {$unwind: '$category'},
    // Reshape the documents to create the element field
    {$project: {element: '$category.target'}},
    // Only include docs with an element
    {$match: {element: {$exists: true}}}
])
```

Result:

```javascript
"result" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : "1",
        "element" : "element 1"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "1",
        "element" : "element 2"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "3",
        "element" : "element 1"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "3",
        "element" : "element 2"
    }
]
```

Comment: Is there another possibility to get the same result without aggregate? I'm asking because this isn't supported by meteor - which I'm using. I would need a aggragate-package and have to do that on server side...

Comment: @user3848987 You'd have to do the unwinding and reshaping of the documents in your own code with `find`.